# Share my maths video on the internet

Tags: education, online-resources

I make some videos of math courses on the internet and some of them are in English. I want to find some where to upload it. Who can help me with this issue? I only know about Youtube, but that is stopped by the Chinese Great Wall. Any other places? (for maths or science is best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really too bad google video no longer accepts uploads from the user community. The best I can do is to point you to wikipedia's entry on competing [video hosting services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_services) and let you make up your mind which one is best for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://www.videolectures.net

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @EdGorcenski: That makes little sense when the question explicitly asked for links. The question may be bad (since it is not really MSE's task to be a link collection), but given what the question is, there seems to be nothing wrong with the answer in particular.